# Mongoose not saving my new document in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, react-redux

so my code is that:

```
router.put("/add-task/:id", auth, boardAuth, async (req, res) => {
  const listId = req.params.id;

  try {
    const board = await Board.findOne({ _id: req.board._id });
    if (!board) return res.status(404).send("no such board");

    const list = await List.findOne({ _id: listId });
    if (!list) return res.status(404).send("List not found");

    const task = new Task({
      text: req.body.text,
    });

    list.cards.push(task);

    board.boardLists.forEach((list) => {
      if (listId.toString() === list._id.toString()) {
        list.cards.push(task);
      } else {
        console.log('no task');
      }
    });
    await board.save();
    await list.save();
    res.send(board);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

i want to save task (card) inside the board object.

my res is that:

```
"boardMembers": [
        "5f326c2e8b906103642af93b"
    ],
    "boardLists": [
        {
            "cards": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f63147c14ba4d4464e263ea",
                    "text": "two"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5f622ca82e6edf1eb8dab7b7",
            "title": "list number one",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5f622c702e6edf1eb8dab7b6",
    "boardName": "board one",
    "boardPassword": "123456",
    "boardCreator": "5f326c2e8b906103642af93b",
    "g_createdAt": "2020-09-16T15:17:04.012Z",
    "__v": 2
```

the problem is when i refresh or sending request again the array of cards is empty again. its not saving the last doc ("two") i added. what i am doing worng here?

update - schema of board

this is the Boardschema

```
const boardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  boardName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxLength: 255,
    minLength: 2,
  },
  boardPassword: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
    maxlength: 255,
  },
  g_createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  boardCreator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  boardMembers: Array,
  boardLists: Array,
});

const Board = mongoose.model("Board", boardSchema);
```

this is the List schema

```
const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxLength: 255,
    minLength: 1,
  },
  cards: Array,
});

const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);
```

this is the Task schema:

```
const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxLength: 1024,
    minLength: 2,
  },
 taskOf: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "List" },
});
```

Comment: If your card is a separated document that you are referencing in the boardMembers you should save it too, otherwise that data doesn´t persist in your database

Comment: if i save the card its will add new collection of cards but its not saving to the board object
in the model of Board : boardLists: Array

Comment: Could you provide the Schemas you are working with?

Comment: i edited the question with the Board schema

Comment: In order to provide a good answer I need to have the List schema and the Task schema...

Comment: edited again with list and task as you ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cascade your reference fields in the opposite direction:

```
const boardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    boardName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxLength: 255,
        minLength: 2,
    },
    boardPassword: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 6,
        maxlength: 255,
    },
    g_createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    boardCreator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    boardMembers: Array,
    boardLists: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "lists" }],
});

const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxLength: 255,
        minLength: 1,
    },
    cards: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "tasks" }],
});

const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxLength: 1024,
        minLength: 2,
    },
});

const List = mongoose.model("lists", listSchema);
const Board = mongoose.model("boards", boardSchema);
const Task = mongoose.model("tasks", boardSchema);
```

See if data gets persisted following this logic

Comment: but now its not added to the Board.boardlists.(some list).cards.
the boardlists is array of IDs... and not like i said before

so for getting the data in client i need to make a call for list by id and call of tasks by id?

Comment: The logic I assume you want to follow is creating a new board, then adding a new board list or set of board lists that consists in a set of new tasks. Each one has it´s own schema, therefore, you should reference them as I´ve shown you. The if you want to add a new task to the board list, just find that list and add the new task, as it´s references it should all be updated fine...

Comment: yes but with this logic in the object of board the array of boardlists includes just IDs and not like before with objects. is that a good way to to that?

Comment: Yes, when you fetch it you can populate the refs array, take a look at this https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html